# Generate media url from file path in Django

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have a function that writes a file to `MEDIA_ROOT`:

```
def write_file():
    with open(settings.MEDIA_ROOT / 'myfile.txt') as file:
        file.write('foobar')
```

Now I want the absolute URL for this file as it is served from `MEDIA_URL`. Does Django have any utility function to do this for me? Or do I need to build it myself?

Note this file is NOT associated with a model's `FileField`.

Answer (score 1):

```
# absolute_path?
# absolute_url?
# views.py

def example_view(request):
    current_domain = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    file_url = current_domain + settings.MEDIA_URL + 'myfile.txt'
    context = {'file_url': file_url}
    return render(request, 'example.html', context)
```

Comment: So it looks like I need to build the URL myself and there's no helper function in Django to do it. Is that right?

Comment: If it is stored to the database, you should choose the relative url.  The only difference is the lack of host.

Comment: I'm not using any database models here. I have set `MEDIA_ROOT` to a relative URL. But I need an absolute URL. It sounds like I'll need to do something similar to what you show here to build it.